# Show that $(a,b) +\alpha = (a+\alpha,b+\alpha)$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $a<b$ are real numbers. Show that $(a,b) +\alpha = (a+\alpha,b+\alpha)$.

How do we add a number to an interval? Is this considered to be a translation? If so, isn't obvious this is true as $a < x < b$ and by adding $\alpha$ to both sides gives us $a+\alpha < b+\alpha$?

Comment: Where did this come from? It is very strange notation.

Comment: Does this question pertain to phase shifts?

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered a definition rather than something you have to prove?

Comment: To prove this, you would actually require a certain set of axioms and definitions, i.e. the definition of interval, the definition of summing interval and a number,...
That being said, I agree with what @WillSherwood said.

Comment: Well, the notation is not as strange as it looks at first. Similar to the notation $v + U := \left\{ v + u \mid u \in U \right\}$ for the equivalence class of $v$, I would interpret $(a,b) + \alpha$ as $\left\{ \beta + \alpha \mid \beta \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R} \right\}$.